# Storing values in bytecode format

Tags: bytecode, vm-implementation

I have created a prototype VM in Java (as it is the language I am the most comfortable with) and I am trying to store the instructions in a bytecode format. I am wondering how I can store values in bytecode, since *byte*s can only be 0 through 255.

As an example:

```
push 4752
```

Push would have the opcode value of 0.
But how could I store 4752? It doesn't fit into a single byte.
I could store values in 4 bytes, therefor allowing them to be 32-bit integers, but then I would have to decide wether to load an opcode (1 byte) or a value (4 bytes). Currently I pass the program as an integer array and the VM loops through the array and executes opcodes. If an opcode requires a value it takes it from the array and then increases the program counter to skip the value, so that it doesn't get executed.

I have tried to work out how virtual machines like the JVM do this, but I was unable to find out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JVM has several options to allow smaller encoding of cases that are expected to be more frequent, and thus on average smaller encoding of methods and classes. Specifically see the following instructions under 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5 (or se8, but IIRC none of the basic arithmetic/computation instructions were changed between 7 and 8, only one or two of the *invoke* instructions):

- *iconst_<i>* are individual opcodes that push specific values "m1" (-1) through 5
- *bipush* pushes the next one-byte from the instruction stream
- *sipush* pushes the next two-bytes from the instruction stream
- *ldc* or *ldc_w* pushes a four-byte value from the constant pool, selected by an *index* in the instruction stream

Your example value 4752 fits in two bytes and would use *sipush*.

To extend  your question, `long` (64-bit or 8-byte) values in JVM are mostly created by pushing an `int` then widening it, or by pushing the value from a `long` variable or field (or method return). There is one instruction *ldc2_w* to push a 2-cell (8-byte) value from the constant pool, and two special-for-frequent instructions *lconst_0* and *lconst_1* for 0 and 1.